# Edit, delete and update gridview with validation and textbox on it

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I have four text-boxes, two buttons one grid-view and one check-box and i put require field validation on each text-box i have a database so that when i enter value in the text-boxes and press submit button data store in the database and show in gird as i use datatable. i Have edit, delete and update link in my grid-view now when i click on edit or delete link validation error message displayed and i won't make changes in my grid. can any one help me on this.

Thanks in advance

My aspx code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

</head>
<body style="height: 191px">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                FirstName</td>
            <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="tFirstName" ErrorMessage="Enter First Name">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                Last name</td>
            <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="tLastName" ErrorMessage="Enter Last Name">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                Age</td>
            <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tAge" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="tAge" ErrorMessage="" dalega">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style7">
                Is Active</td>
            <td class="style8">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="dropActive" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                Auto ID</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="autoID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="autoID" ErrorMessage="Marzi hai teri">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style6">
                </td>
            <td class="style5">
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Sumit" ValidationGroup="abc"/>
    <input type="reset" />
                <br />   
                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" Height="72px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4" colspan="2">
                 <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Green" EnableViewState="false" />
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="36%" OnRowEditing="EditRow" OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEditRow" OnRowUpdating="UpdateRow" DataKeyNames="AutoId" OnRowDeleting="DeleteRow" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="ChangePage" AllowSorting="True">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="AutoId" DataField="AutoId" ReadOnly="true" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("FirstNAme") %></ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'/>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("LastName") %></ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'/>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Age">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("Age") %></ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Age") %>' Columns="3" />
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="REw" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAge" Text="*" /> 
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active?">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("Active").ToString().Equals("True") ? "Yes" : "No" %>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="dropActive" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Active") %>'>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="True" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete?">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" ForeColor="Red" CommandName="Delete" />
            </span>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<EditRowStyle BackColor="#efefef" />
<FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
<SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
<SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
 </asp:GridView>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                   </body>
                   </html>
```

code for aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        PopulateData();
    }
}
protected void EditRow(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    this.PopulateData();
}
protected void CancelEditRow(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    this.PopulateData();
}
protected void DeleteRow(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    var autoID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EMS;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        string sql = "Delete from PersonalDetail" +" where AutoId = @AutoId";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AutoId", autoID);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    lblMessage.Text ="Record has been deleted successfully !";
    lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.
    Color.Red;
    this.PopulateData();
}
protected void ChangePage(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    this.PopulateData();
}
protected void UpdateRow(object sendedr, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    var autoID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex] as GridViewRow;
    TextBox tFirstName = row.FindControl("txtFirstName") as TextBox;
    TextBox tLastName = row.FindControl("txtLastName") as TextBox;
    TextBox tAge = row.FindControl("txtAge") as TextBox;
    DropDownList dropActive = row.FindControl("dropActive") as DropDownList;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EMS;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        string sql = "Update PersonalDetail set FirstName = @FirstName,LastName=@LastName, Age= @Age, Active = @Active" + " where AutoId = @AutoId";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", tFirstName.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", tLastName.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", tAge.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", dropActive.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AutoId", autoID);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    lblMessage.Text ="Record updated successfully !";
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    this.PopulateData();
}
private void PopulateData()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EMS;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        string sql = "Select * from PersonalDetail";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                ad.Fill(table);
            }
        }
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EMS;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();

    string FirstName = tFirstName.Text;
    string LastName = tLastName.Text;
    string Age = tAge.Text;
    string Active = dropActive.Text;
    string AutoId = autoID.Text;

    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into PersonalDetail(FirstName,LastName,Age,Active,AutoId) values('" + FirstName + "','" + LastName + "','" + Age + "','" + Active + "','" + AutoId + "')";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", tFirstName.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", tLastName.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", tAge.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", dropActive.Text.Trim());

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AutoId", autoID.Text.Trim());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    con.Close();
    tFirstName.Text = string.Empty;
    tLastName.Text = string.Empty;
    tAge.Text = string.Empty;
    dropActive.Text = string.Empty;
    tFirstName.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> None of your `Validation` control has a `Validation Group`.
>   Add this to all your `RequiredFieldValidator`.

```
ValidationGroup="SomeName"
```

> Make sure all your `RequiredFieldValidator` has the same `ValidationGroup`
>   Now finally add the  `ValidationGroup="SomeName"` to your `Button` control which when clicked raises the Validation controls.

Comment: i have to put validation group only on button and link or for all validation also

Comment: just put validation group on all the requiredfieldvalidators and the button control that will raise the valdations(in your case its the button with id Button1). Dont do anything insde the Gridview. Keept it as it is.

Comment: after putting validation group on requiredfield validator when i press submit button it will add record in database not showing error message.

Comment: You need to put the ValidationGroup on the submit button as well. And keep the name of the ValidationGroup same across all the  requiredfieldvalidator and the submit button control.

Comment: can u help in one more thing when i enter value and press submit button it will show in the gridview but it will only show only existing records

Answer (score 1):

I just use this.populate(); on button1 to show grid-view after enter details in the text-boxes thanks for your reply guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing validation checking from your link `CauseValidation="false"`

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton CauseValidation="false" ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
</ItemTemplate>
```